# Cloudera user not alowed to manipulate hdfs system on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, solr, cloudera

I am trying to create a folder in hdfs hadoop file system but it is not allowing me to create a folder using the user cloudera nor as root. What should I configure to make it to allow me to hier was my attempt:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo hadoop fs -mkdir /solr/test_core
mkdir: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/solr":solr:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ su
Password:
[root@quickstart cloudera]# hadoop fs -mkdir /solr/test_core
mkdir: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE,inode="/solr":solr:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
[root@quickstart cloudera]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:
You should use these weird command.

> sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir /solr/test_core/

Answer (score 1):

Neither cloudera nor root users will have permissions to run any command on `/solr`

to run any command you need to change into hdfs and then issue the commands like below:

```
su - hdfs
hadoop fs -mkdir /solr/test_core/
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To switch user to hdfs:

   `sudo su - hdfs`.
   Then you can make directory under /solr
2. To switch back to cloudera user

   `su - cloudera`
   and enter the password for cloudera